# How to 'double lock' a file so multiple people must approve its access

Tags: linux, security

I have a slightly odd situation. I help run a chat network which allows people to chat in public groups, and in private message.

People are happy with logging the public chat but feel it would be a huge privacy violation to log the private chats. The network is specifically aimed at young people and so a few of us really want to log private chats because we think it would be a poor position to be in if an allegation was made and we said we didn't log anything in private because our volunteers were concerned for their privacy.

So, I'm wondering if we can implement some sort of mechanism where at least two people have to approve the reading of a log file.

I know in principle we could do this e.g. the file is encrypted using two people's keys, but that doesn't scale to having say 6 people with access to the log files location.

We also need to account for say one person with access disappearing or dying - we need two other trusted people from this group of six to be able to access the file.

Alternatively - any other ideas on ways of setting people's mind at ease that you're not spending your free time (what is this?) snooping on people's conversations? Access alerts etc?

Comment: Use a sql, not filesystem storage for your chat data?

Comment: This is a hard problem and can't be solved on the file system/OS level,  this kind of access control must be implemented by the software. As an easier approach, you could implement proper access auditing (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/chap-system_auditing.html)

Comment: @yagmoth555 sure, but the application would need password or privkey to access the database server instance, which would be available to other sudoers. I know deep down that no matter what we do, if someone has root access, they can access it, even as far as writing an LKM to intercept the data in realtime.

Comment: password or private key ? the application never access it directly.. You need an third part application that will act as a hub to retrive the data, and that application will be able to see what to share, and to who. You never give the server access to anyone. That mean your own built-in authentification will handle access to the hub, and the SQL instance would be encrypted and secured.

Comment: @yagmoth555 and how does the DB server instance authenticate with this hub?

Comment: with a username. my point was your friend never access the server directly, unless they hack the hub or sudo your server, in any case you can't recover that. Your only exit plan is to log nothing and the chat client send directly the chat message to the remote users. As read IRC implentation, as you are triing to rewrite it at the way I see it.

Comment: I'm sorry @yagmoth555 but this comment makes no sense to me.

Comment: Oh well, nevermind. We are not dev anyway there. So I will let you do the design phase of your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a little on @[Sven](https://serverfault.com/users/8897/sven)'s comment, while there are some tools that could make this possible, those tools are not available at OS level.

So there are two parts to the answer:

- establish an official policy about accessing such log files, and as @Sven suggested, make sure you have strong audit controls in place to detect any access to such files. Ensure this policy clarifies that any unauthorised access to these files will have consequences.
- define a workable solution for tracking access requests for such files: it could be something as simple as a generic Change management system where two approvals must be 'given' (i.e. recorded) to allow for such access, or you could consider having a front end handle the whole flow: gathering access requests, processing them and any approvals, and if approvals are given, providing a means of reviewing the data.

Any technical measures would likely be something a sufficiently privileged user could work around, hence the need for a policy defining the rules about all this, and the consequences for failing to abide by those rules.

Comment: Yes, my suspicion was that it would come down to simply having good policies in place from the outset to be honest. I was hoping that there was some magic that I hadn't heard of. Proper access auditing is already on my to-do list so if it's decided that we will log this information we will just have to give that task higher priority. And of course, if we did log this information, we'd need a solid access policy and circumstances warranting access would be quite strict. Thank you for taking the time to comment :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using secret sharing and threshold RSA.

You can create a secret shared RSA key which can be recovered from whatever fraction of keys you decide. A key which can be recovered from 2 out of 6 shares is just one of the endless possibilities.

Then you use the public key to encrypt the logs. This will follow standard practice for public key encryption where each time you start an encrypted log, the server choose a random symmetrical key for encryption (for example using AES). The symmetrical key itself is then encrypted using the RSA public key. The symmetrical key stays in memory during decryption but is never saved in clear. This encryption can be done using standard software.

When decryption is needed a number of key share holders agree that a certain log needs to be decrypted and apply their share of the RSA key to the encrypted symmetrical key. This result in a secret sharing of the symmetrical key. These shares of the symmetrical key can then be exchanged among the parties who can then reconstruct the symmetrical key and decrypt the chosen log file.